# Docker Compose specify .docker directory?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

With docker I can specify a specific config to use by doing `docker --config /var/vcap/store run ***`

How I can I do the same thing with `docker-compose` so that I can specify a `.docker` directory that contains my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `DOCKER_CONFIG` environment variable you can specify the location of your configuration.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#description